# Send SMTP with From address of another domain

Tags: email, proxy, smtp

My goal is to create a canned email on my server and then send the email from client email addresses. To do this and not be marked as spam I understand it must come from a domain matching the from address. 
There are many user email addresses I would need to send email from, all with the same domain. With cooperation from my client, could I set this up to work with one SMTP credential or would I need credentials for each and every individual user?

To clarify, if I get an SMTP server address with a un/pw from my client, would that be enough to send from:

george@example.com
martha@example.com
ted@example.com

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

You want to avoid [joe-jobbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_job) in your automated messages.

#### Your Options

It depends on how you're submitting jobs to the MTA.

1. If you're authenticating to a remote SMTP server for each message, then you need credentials for each user.
2. If you're injecting messages directly into an MTA (e.g. with the *sendmail* command) that is authorized to send mail for the domain, then you only need privileged access.

Answer (score 2):

It depends completely on the SMTP server you are using. Some servers will allow this, like Google's SMTP, but it will attach a `Sender` header to the outgoing message when the `From` header does not match the authenticated account.

Example:

1. You authenticate with `joe@gmail.com`
2. You send out with `From: bill@gmail.com`
3. The message will contain `From: bill@gmail.com`, but Google will attach
   `Sender: joe@gmail.com` to the message headers.

So, it completely depends on the SMTP server and [their policy](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22370).