# Sending Emails out with From Address from different domain

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email, outlook

I work for a subscription fulfillment company, where we handle the subscriptions to various magazines (renewals, invoices primarily).  So we email out to the subscribers when they purchase a magazine, that we are charging them for their monthly/annually renewal or they sent us a question about their subscription and we are answering them.

As of right now, we are creating email addresses on our domain for each of our clients (the publishers), but the publishers want us to send out the emails with their domain name as the from (not ours).

I know this can be done because we purchased email blasting software and it does it without a problem (the clients put in SPF records so that it won't be marked as SPAM).  The problem is that when our .Net (specifically VB.Net) application goes to send out emails with a From from a different domain, I get back that the user we authenticated to our internal SMTP server with isn't authorized to send out on behalf of the From.

I got a partial idea from [Send SMTP with From address of another domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055481/send-smtp-with-from-address-of-another-domain) that maybe I could ask the publishers to issue us credentials to their SMTP server and have the .Net code try using their server and credentials to send out the email, but I would prefer not to go that route.

On the same note, our people use Outlook 2010 to answer most of the customer service emails, so it would be good if the solution for the .Net could also work for Outlook.  If it doesn't, it doesn't, but at least the .Net one is a step in the right direction.

Now, I am a .Net developer, not an SMTP administrator (but I'm the closest to it that we have).  So any instructions need to be detailed, please assume that I am ignorant in this area, so if you say go run program such and such, please state where program such and such is.

Comment: Is that an Exchange mailbox with multipel proxy addresses from different domains?

Comment: I'm running an Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 SP1.  I believe it is setup for my companies domain only.  Beyond that, I don't know.

Comment: Exchange would not let you spoof the sender email address. If sending from Outlook, it will always use the default SMTP address. You can send using one of the proxy addresses that belong to the mailbox in question if you can create a dummy POP3/SMTP account in Outlook or use a product like Proxy Manager (http://www.dimastr.com/proxyman)